# How to add an existing android sdk to the Android Studio 1.2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I downloaded the latest version of android studio from its official website. I've downloaded the sdk files separately before and now I want to add it to the android studio files.

I simply copy the sdk folder into android studio folder. Then I ran the android studio file but it throw an error(the following pics):

[image: Android Studio Error]

and after I click `OK` it closes. I saw the following links but they couldn't help because they can open their Android Studio:

- [Android Studio using existing android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582892/android-studio-using-existing-android-sdk)
- [How do you add an SDK to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594611/how-do-you-add-an-sdk-to-android-studio)

**Details**
*I'm using Linux Mint 17 64bit. Android Studio v1.2*

**Update**

I removed the sdk folder and it showed me the following window! but nothing changed and the previous error is thrown.

[image: Proxy windows error after removing sdk folder]

Comment: Delete the copied SDK and Android Studio and perform a clean re-installation of Android Studio.

Comment: You can delete the copied SDK and launch Android Studio, it will prompt you to introduce where the SDK is, and then you select the right folder.

Comment: why have You done it? All is completely installed with the Android Studio set up...just deinstall AS and install again like desscribed in the API Help for installing AS

Comment: @Robert What do you mean by installation? 
@joaquin I've deleted the `sdk` folder and re run the `idea.sh` file but the proxy setting s pop up. I'll update the question now.
@Opiatefuchs I saw that Android Studio folder structure has a sdk folder(for those who have installed it from Android Studio). So I thought that if I copy it there, it will search for `sdk` folder and find it :)